# Phonegap on Windows Phone 8.1 with AngularJS can't retrieve JSONP from my API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I made an app with Phonegap Cordova and when I test it on Android everything is OK, but when I test it on Windows Phone 8.1 it gives me the following error:

> APPHOST9601: Can’t load http://www.example.com/apiv2/process.php/Login2?Email=xxxx@xxxx.com&Password=7c4a8d09ca3762af61e59520943dc26494f8941b&callback=angular.callbacks._0. An app can’t load remote web content in the local context. File: index.html. I am using Angularjs and Onsenui.

EDITED:

The code is:

```
var apiprincipal = 'http://www.example.com/apiv2/process.php/';
 // Log In Controller
  app.controller('loginController', [ '$http', '$scope', '$rootScope', function($http, $scope, $rootScope){

    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.password = '';

    $scope.loginN = function(){

      if($scope.email==='' && $scope.password===''){         

        ons.notification.alert({message: "Vo\u00E7\u00EA dever\u00E1 preencer os dois campos usu\u00E1rio e senha"});

      } else {

        modal.show();

          $http.jsonp(apiprincipal+'Login2?Email='+$scope.email+'&Password='+CryptoJS.SHA1($scope.password)+'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(
            function(response){

              if(response.status=='ok'){

                 console.log('WORKING')

              } else{

                modal.hide();

              }

            }
          );


      }

    };

  }]);
```

Comment: It appears you may be using a method which violates security restrictions for Windows 8.1 devices.  Can you list the code that you are executing which is causing this error for review?

Comment: this seems like a CORS issue

Comment: Definitely a CORS issue.  You need to add headers for Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: but i have in my config app  file <access origin="*" />,what is wrong? if i running the app with adroid, the app work like a charm, but if i build to windows phone give that error.

Comment: you haven't listed the code which shows this.

Comment: and what you think about the problem? how can imake work the app with wp8

Comment: Definitely not a CORS issue, cause JSONP doesn't get such issues.

Comment: I used JSONP and I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

First, try removing some unnecessary code for a more readable question.

Your URL should look like this

```
$http.jsonp(apiprincipal+'Login2?Email='+$scope.email+'&Password='+CryptoJS.SHA1($scope.password)+'&_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK')
```

in case that `&_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK` doesn't work, change it for `?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK`

I was with the same in my app and yesterday I was reading an article, so I fix it like this:

```
http://amyurl.com/wp-json/posts?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK
```

now it is working.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, I had to change my JSONP call to a GET call like `$http.get(...`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue when targeting Windows 8.1.

First I checked my backend supported CORS. I didn't find a way to keep JSONP in Windows 8.1, I had to change it into a simple GET method. Then I removed 'callback' from the URL.

Referring to your code, it should look like that

```
$http.get(apiprincipal+'Login2?Email='+$scope.email+'&Password='+CryptoJS.SHA1($scope.password)).success(function(response) {

    if(response.status=='ok'){

        console.log('WORKING');

    } else{

        modal.hide();
    }
});
```

It worked fine for me, hope it can help someone else.